# Tell x2goclient to capture the windows key?

Tags: remote-access, keyboard-events

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine, connecting to multiple Debian linux machines (stable, up-to-date) via x2go. I'd like x2go to grab the Windows key when I'm working within the remote linux system. I've looked at the x2go docs, searched the web, and looked at the local x2go client files, but found nothing.

When I connect to a remote Windows Terminal Server, that machine captures the Windows key, so I know in theory it is possible for the remote to obtain the Windows key press.

If this is not possible, are there other ways to make the remote desktop connection from Windows 10 to linux such that I could accomplish this?

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the following solution.

In the X2GO client, go to your client settings (not the session preferences) and go to the `X.Org Server settings` tab. Here select custom server, go to your vcxsrv executable. Windows default location: `C:/Program Files (x86)/x2goclient/VcXsrv/vcxsrv.exe`

For the command line options, add `-keyhook` this will grab all pressed keys and forward them to the session. For me I use `-multiwindow -notrayicon -clipboard -keyhook`

Comment: Thank you! Very nice to be able to use awesome window manager via x2go, rather than LXQT.

Comment: This works! Make sure your path to vcxsrv.exe exists, otherwise like I had to you will need to go into registry (if on Windows of course) and fix your settings, specifically in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Obviously Nice\x2goclient\settings I had to set xexec string key to C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe

Comment: This suggestion doesn't seem to work (anymore, at least).

Comment: @Synthead it does work. I just needed this again and found the same answer. Be sure to also restart x2go client completely, not just the session.